# Matrix issue in Rmarkdown

Tags: r

I created a function in r that calculates the number of replicates necessary.  My issue is that I am required to put some value for delta and sigma in matrices and then into the function.

```
required.replicates <- function(delta, sigma, z.alpha = 1.959964, 
  z.beta=0.8416212)
{
r.exact <- (2*(z.alpha + z.beta)^2)*(sigma/delta)^2
result <- list(delta, sigma, z.alpha, z.beta)
names(result) <- c("delta", "sigma", "z.alpha", "z.beta")
r.integer <- ceiling(r.exact)
replicate.output <- list(result, r.exact, r.integer)
names(replicate.output) <- c("result","r.exact","r.integer")
return(replicate.output)
}

sigma.vec <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12)
delta.vec <- c(1,2,5,8,10)
sigma.mat <- matrix(rep(sigma.vec,times=length.s), nrow =length.s, 
   byrow=TRUE)
delta.mat <- matrix(rep(delta.vec,times=length.s), ncol = length.s, 
   byrow=FALSE)
required.replicates(delta= delta.mat, sigma=sigma.mat)
```

Error in sigma/delta : non-conformable arrays

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error message.

Comment: What do you want to achive? `sigma.mat` is a `(10*6)` matrix, while `delta.mat`  is `(5*10)`, so it's not clear to me what `sigma.mat / delta.mat` shall produce.

Comment: Sorry about that.  What I need to do is put all of the values in sigma.vec and the delta.vec through the formula in required.replicates.

Answer (score 1):

`sigma.vec` and `delta.vec` have different lengths, so `sigma.mat` and `delta.mat` have different dimensions, so `sigma.mat/delta.mat` produces error.

Comment: The assignment just wants these 30 possible combinations covered by repeating the rows of the sigma.vec and the columns of delta.vec

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you're missing `length.s`, which you are using to store the lengths of both `sigma.vec` and `delta.vec`. I would save the lengths as separate vars:

```
length.s <- length(sigma.vec)
length.d <- length(delta.vec)
```

Your main issue `non-conformable arrays` appears to stem from the fact that `sigma.vec` and `delta.vec` are different lengths, which leads to different `matrix` dimensions. Add one more element to `delta.vec` or remove one from `sigma.vec` and I think your function should work.